# ipv6 netfilter in android/linux kernel for udp traffic

Tags: android, linux, hook, ipv6, netfilter

I wrote a netfilter implementation for ipv4 in kernel and it works fine. I browsed internet and I was not able to find a example to write a ipv6 netfilter in kernel. I have a rough idea how to write it. Can you please help me correct the mistakes in it. This code resulted in a kernel panic. I will give you the outline of the code.

```
sa.hook = hookfunction;
sa.hooknum = NF_INET_POST_ROUTING;
sa.pf = PF_INET6;
sa.priority = NF_IP6_PRI_LAST;
nf_register_hook(&sa);

hookfunction() {
    struct ipv6hdr *ipv6;
    struct udphdr *udp;
    ipv6 = (struct ipv6hdr *) skb_network_header(skb);
    udp = (struct udphdr *) skb_transport_header(skb);
    //printing the values of src add, dest add, src port, dst port
    NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Comment: skb mention above is struct sk_buff (struct sk_buff *skb)

Comment: Can you post the full code, or a small subset of it that does panic? The outline itself does not show anything that would cause any runtime errors.